# Haskell: Higher order functions

Tags: haskell

**The Problem:**

Implement the higher order insertion sort algorithm hoMergeSort which
is similar to merge sort except that an element x is placed before an
element y if fun x < fun y where fun :: a -> b is a function taken as
input by higher order merge sort. In other words, the result of evaluating
hoMergeSort fun xs should be a list [y1,y2,..., yn] such that
fun y1 < fun y2 < ... < fun yn.

My non-working attempt:

```
homerge :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
homerge _ xs [] = xs
homerge _ [] ys = ys
homerge fun (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (fun x)<(fun y) then fun x : (homerge fun xs (y:ys)) 
                            else y : (homerge fun (x:xs) ys)
```

I've been trying to get my head around this problem for the past hour and a half and have been making no progress. The way I've written my code makes sense to me but the compiler is not having any of it.

Not looking for someone to completely solve the question for me, just set me on the right track of thinking.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a working implementation of a regular merge sort?

Comment: Yes - `msort [] = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort xs = merge (msort ys) (msort ws)
where (ys,ws) = (take l xs, drop l xs)
where l = length xs ‘div‘ 2`

Comment: `merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x<y then x : merge xs (y:ys)
else y : merge (x:xs) ys`

Comment: "the compiler is not having any of it" and the error message is.......?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to insert `x` into the list, not `fun x`. Here is a function that should work:

```
homerge :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
homerge _ xs [] = xs
homerge _ [] ys = ys
homerge f (x:xs) (y:ys) | f x < f y = x : homerge f xs (y:ys)
                        | otherwise = y : homerge f (x:xs) ys
```

Note I used guards because they make the code much more clear then if-then-else. Also this only merges two already-sorted lists.

Comment: hey lorenzo, wonder if u can help me with this one aswell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083024/haskell-function-to-sort-1st-element-of-3-tuples-lexicographically