# Haskell: function to sort 1st element of 3 tuples lexicographically

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have a spreadsheet :: [(String,String,Int)] containing
triples (name, user,mark) where name is the lastname of a student, user
is his username and mark is the result of the student’s first CW.
Write a function sortLastname that sorts a spreadsheet lexicographically
by names using the higher order insertion sort defined in Exercise 2.

My code for exercise 2:

```
homerge :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
homerge _ xs [] = xs
homerge _ [] ys = ys
homerge fun (x:xs) (y:ys) | fun x < fun y = x : homerge fun xs (y:ys)
                          | otherwise = y : homerge fun (x:xs) ys`


hoMergeSort :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
hoMergeSort _ [x] = [x]
hoMergeSort fun xs = homerge fun (hoMergeSort fun ys) (hoMergeSort fun ws)
                 where (ys,ws) = (take l xs, drop l xs)
                               where l = length xs `div` 2
```

My current attempt:

```
sortLastName [(x,y,z)] = hoMergeSort ( (x,_,_) (x',_,_) = x<x' ) [(x,y,z)]
```

My problem is getting the correct function to check whether the first element of 3-tuple is less than the next element.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are guessing at haskell's syntax. I think this question is a little too broad (SO is not a homework writing service). Maybe you can cut this down to one specific problem? For instance you are having trouble with the first argument to `hoMergeSort`, so why not remove all the other parts of your question and ask about `( (x,_,_) (x',_,_) = x<x' )`: what type is this supposed to have? What do you want it to do? What errors do you get from the compiler and what specifically is confusing you about them?

Comment: Sorry, I thought i specified. What I mean is what sort of code will allow to me compare the 1st elements of the tuples with a function in place of `( (x,_,_) (x',_,_) = x<x' )`

Comment: Did you understand your solution to exercise 2 after you wrote it? Probably worth making sure you do understand it before moving on to the later steps

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @henahzurfdsa! We generally add the `homework` tag for homework-related questions, could you edit your post to add the tag? While you're at it, don't hesitate to include the clarification in your comment (saying that you're looking for a replacement for `( (x,_,_) (x',_,_) = x<x' )`) in your post. Other than that, it seems to me that this is a well-written question — it shows what you tried and asks something clear :) .

Answer (score 0):

Let's not run. Let's move slowly with this:

```
-- sortLastName [(x,y,z)] = hoMergeSort ( (x,_,_) (x',_,_) = x<x' ) [(x,y,z)]
sortLastName xyzs = hoMergeSort fun xyzs
    where
```

Let's look into that definition for a moment,

```
-- homerge fun (x:xs) (y:ys) | fun x < fun y = x : homerge fun xs (y:ys)
```

See, we have `fun x` and `fun y` there? The results of which go as operands into the `<` comparison?

```
    fun (x,y,z) =
```

which value from those available here do we want to go into the `<` comparison as an operand?

```
                  .....
```

`fun` isn't used for comparison. *That* is done by `<`, in your source code of the function `homerge`. The `fun` function is used to *supply the value* to be used in that comparison.

Go slowly, get far.

---

Note that this is not lexicographical order. This is ordering by nth field of a triple, regardless of the values of the other fields. The lexicographical order is rather

```
(x,y,z) < (a,b,c) = x < a || x==a && (y < b || y==b && z < c)
```

Comment: The ordering you define in the last sentence seems wrong. In particular, with that order, (1,2,3) < (3,2,1) is true, but so is (3,2,1) < (1,2,3).

Comment: The OP is looking to sort "lexicographically by names", so they want the lexicographical order on the first field `("bar","zozo",9) < ("foo","alfa",2)` because `"bar" < "foo"`. So I'd argue it *is* the lexicographical order (on a projection, not on the whole tuple).

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron on re-reading the post, I think you're right. fortunately, strings are already compared lexicographically, by `<`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
-- ( (x,_,_) (x',_,_) = x<x' )
```

is not quite valid. To create an anonymous function, use the syntax `\arg -> result`. If you were to write the above, the result would be is another function which returns `x<x'`:

```
-- \(x,_,_) -> ( \(x',_,_) -> x<x' )
-- i.e. without the parentheses:
-- \(x,_,_) -> \(x',_,_) -> x<x'
```

As @WillNess pointed out, you are already doing the comparison `fun x < fun y` inside the definition of `homerge`.

The `fun` argument should therefore be a projection from the whole tuple to the part that you want to compare.

```
\(x,_,_) -> x
```

The whole sortLastName function is then:

```
sortLastName xyzs = hoMergeSort (\(name,_,_) -> name) xyzs where
```

As @WillNess suggested, you can use the `where` syntax which is very practical for small helper definitions:

```
sortLastName xyzs = hoMergeSort fun xyzs where
  fun (name,_,_) = name
```

Note that by supplying only a comparison, you cannot easily reverse the order. If the `name` field was a `Num`, you could return `0-x`, i.e. `\(x,_,_) -> -x` to sort in descending order, but for strings there is no practical way to do this. It would therefore be better if you modified `hoMergeSort` so that it accepts a comparison with two arguments, instead of expecting a projection of a single argument.